# Textbox disabled after certain date is met

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I need it so that the text areas for preferredFirstName and preferredLastName are disabled/readonly if the date is after 8/15/2015. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<%-- ***** BEGIN PREFERRED NAME SECTION ***** --%>
    <hr />
    <h2>Preferred Name for Name Badge (if different than above)</h2 >
      <fieldset>
      <label class="not-required">Preferred First Name
      <input type="text" name="preferredFirstName" id="preferredFirstName" size="25" maxlength="25"<%=formFields.getTextValue("preferredFirstName")%> />
      </label>
      <label class="not-required">Preferred Last Name
      <input type="text" name="preferredLastName" id="preferredLastName" size="25" maxlength="25"<%=formFields.getTextValue("preferredLastName")%> />
      </label>
      </fieldset>
       <%-- ***** END PREFERRED NAME SECTION ***** --%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're going to use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dueDate = new Date("8/15/2015");
    var today = new Date();
    if(today > dueDate){
        $("#preferredFirstName").prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#preferredLastName").prop("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ar5mkdfo/

Comment: Thank you .. This worked.. I was trying to do it on my own using jquery but after I saw your example I now know where I went wrong.